# Decomposition of vector bundle in $M$-theory

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, compactification, calabi-yau, algebraic-geometry

I was studying [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0303) where the authors construct some field theory solutions by wrapping M5-branes on holomorphic curves on Calabi-Yau. I have some questions about their construction.

What they do is to consider the local geometry (2.1) $$\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow X \rightarrow C_g$$ where $X$ is a Calabi-Yau three-fold. They proceed by stating that to preserve supersymmetry the *determinant line bundle* of $X$ should be the canonical bundle $K_{C_g}$ of the curve.

> Here is my first question: why and how this geometric constrain is needed to preserve supersymmetry? Is it some sort of topological twist?

Then they proceed in stating that this condition imposes that $X$ has to be of the form $X=K_{C_g}\otimes V$ where $V$ is an arbitrary $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-bundle over the curve (are they talking about principal bundle?). Now, depending on the specific form of this last bundle, we get different solutions and here is the big catch:

> When the structure group of $V$ reduces from $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ to $\mathrm{U}(1)$, then $X$ is **decomposable** and the local geometry becomes $$\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_1\oplus\mathcal{L}_2\rightarrow C_g$$ with the condition $$\mathcal{L}_1 \otimes \mathcal{L}_2=K_{C_g}$$

Could someone shed some light on this step? First I don't understand the dimensionality, the direct sum of the two line bundles has complex dimension $2$ while the Calabi-Yau had complex dimension $3$. I would also like some details on the concept of "decomposable" and how this can be understood physically.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised that no expert tried to answer this. It all probably has a simple explanation... For now, the best I can suggest is section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.1467. It starts with an even briefer summary of the passages you're trying to figure out, but argued in a slightly different way, so who knows, maybe something there will make more sense. For example, the author states that

> The Calabi-Yau condition in the neighborhood of the zero section is that the determinant line bundle be equal to the canonical bundle ... of the curve.

... implying that the reason that the determinant line bundle equals the canonical bundle, is to preserve the Calabi-Yau property of X; which is what allows the covariantly constant spinor to exist.

Good luck if you didn't already figure it out! You can always write to the authors if nothing else works. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I actually found another paper where they state that the last geometry is the geometry of the normal bundle to the curve. Which would make sense given that one limit of this geometry is the one of S-class theories where the normal bundle is the cotangent bundle to the curve.